# How to change authenticate method on IIS 7?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I've got an error which tells me unauthorized. How and where to change that webserver allows anonymous (public) access?

**HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized**

[401.2 - Logon failed due to server configuration.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891)

Something has happened on my local machine when I made the latest update for IIS, but now I'm not sure what has happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the following methods here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942043

Answer (score 2):

Select your website on the tree left hand side inside IIS Manager.

Double click on Authentication section from the menu (Authentication section is under the IIS caregory)

Enable Anonymous Auth. there as follows :

[image]

You can bind a user to this app by Editing the Anonymous Auth. Section. this will gives you box like this :

[image]

This should be set to **IUSR** by default.